# Having a variable in the auth password stay encrypted

Tags: paw-app

I'm working with a couple of API's that use basic auth. The credentials differ between environments and I have usernames and passwords as separate variables.
I really like how Paw 3 has encrypted password field and how it hides the base64 representation when using that, is there any way to have an environment variable in the encrypted field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the environments you can put your password in a Secure dynamic value. Then it will stay encrypted:
[image: secure]

To insert it in the Basic Auth Dynamic value you should change to Secure field to Regular field and insert your environment variable in there:
[image: secure1]

Your password will stay encrypted as it is inside a Secure dynamic value:
[image: secure2]